# python cant find where this is coming from

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, split

so i need a little help with my code, so i was doing a python app that launches apps that you chose at the same time (if you want to launch certain apps all together) and yes this was made in a yt video. so i was changing it so it shows the file name, not location, i managed to make it work, but only if i click on the "Choose App" button [this is as soon as i launch the app, it just shows the location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkpkz.png) but when i click on "Choose App" (i can click on it and exit the explorer) the it shows [what i intended it to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noUhZ.png) but i dont know how to make it show it like this when i first launch the app without having to click on "Chose App" and close explorer, is there a way to make it show the name only? even when i first start the app?

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import filedialog, Text
import os

color = "#263D42" #main window color
root = tk.Tk()
apps = [] #saved apps to launch


#design
root.title("Quick apps")
root.iconphoto(False, tk.PhotoImage(file='light.ico'))
#design


#read save file and stuff
if os.path.isfile('QuickAppsave.txt'):
    with open('QuickAppsave.txt', 'r') as f:
        tempApps = f.read()
        tempApps = tempApps.split(',')
        apps = [x for x in tempApps if x.strip()]
    #read save file and stuff


#make a window with color

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=555, width=500, bg=color) #color and size
canvas.pack()#add it to "pack" aka to that window

#make a window with color




#make frame in window

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="white")
frame.place(relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.8, relx=0.1, rely=0.1) #frame

#make frame in window


#Buttons

#Chose app button

def addApp(): #what happens when u click "Chose App" button

        #remove old save of apps so new one added
    for widget in frame.winfo_children():
     widget.destroy()
        #remove old save of apps so new one added

    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("executebles", "*.exe"), ("all files", "*.*")), initialdir="/", title="Select App")
    apps.append(filename)

    for app in apps:
        label = tk.Label(frame, text=app.split('/')[-1], bg="gray")
        label.pack()

openFile = tk.Button(root, text="Choose App", padx=10, pady=5, fg="white", bg=color, command=addApp) #command = im adding what it does
openFile.pack() #add it to "pack" aka to that window (also said "root" in beginning so it is attached to root of window not frame)

#Chose app button


#Start apps button

    #start apps code
def runApps():
    for app in apps:
        os.startfile(app)
    #start apps code

StartApps = tk.Button(root, text="Start Apps", padx=10, pady=5, fg="white", bg=color, command=runApps)
StartApps.pack() #add it to "pack" aka to that window (also said "root" in beginning so it is attached to root of window not frame)

#Start apps button

#reset button
def resetFiles():
    os.remove('QuickAppsave.txt')
    for widget in frame.winfo_children():
     widget.destroy()
    os.startfile('QuickApps.py')
    exit()
    

resetApps = tk.Button(root, text="Reset", padx=10, pady=5, fg="white", bg=color, command=resetFiles)
resetApps.pack() #add it to "pack" aka to that window (also said "root" in beginning so it is attached to root of window not frame)

#reset button

#Buttons
for app in apps:
    label = tk.Label(frame, text=app)
    label.pack()

root.mainloop()



with open('QuickAppsave.txt', 'w') as f:
    for app in apps:
     f.write(app + ',')
```

Comment: this is the part that made it work after i click on "Choose Apps" , idk why it only works after but this is the part:
````for app in apps:
        label = tk.Label(frame, text=app.split('/')[-1], bg="gray")
        label.pack()````

Comment: Did you answer your own question?

Comment: No i was just adding a comment about the part that was supposed to fix it, but ended up making it only work if i click on "Choose App" and close the explorer tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use `.split` again.

```py
def format_path(path):
    return path.split('/')[-1]

# ...
# replace code where the below comment is
#Buttons
for app in apps:
    label = tk.Label(frame, text=format_path(app))
    label.pack()
# ...
```

Full code

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, Text
import os

color = '#263D42'   # main window color
root = tk.Tk()
apps = [] #saved apps to launch


#design
root.title('Quick apps')
root.iconphoto(False, tk.PhotoImage(file='light.ico'))
#design


def format_path(path):
    return path.split('/')[-1]

#read save file and stuff
if os.path.isfile('QuickAppsave.txt'):
    with open('QuickAppsave.txt', 'r') as f:
        tempApps = f.read()
        tempApps = tempApps.split(',')
        apps = [x for x in tempApps if x.strip()]
    #read save file and stuff


#make a window with color

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=555, width=500, bg=color) #color and size
canvas.pack() # add it to "pack" aka to that window

#make a window with color




#make frame in window

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="white")
frame.place(relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.8, relx=0.1, rely=0.1) #frame

#make frame in window


#Buttons

#Chose app button

def addApp(): #what happens when u click "Chose App" button

        #remove old save of apps so new one added
    for widget in frame.winfo_children():
     widget.destroy()
        #remove old save of apps so new one added

    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("executebles", "*.exe"), ("all files", "*.*")), initialdir="/", title="Select App")
    apps.append(filename)

    for app in apps:
        label = tk.Label(frame, text=format_path(app), bg="gray")
        label.pack()

openFile = tk.Button(root, text="Choose App", padx=10, pady=5, fg="white", bg=color, command=addApp) #command = im adding what it does
openFile.pack() #add it to "pack" aka to that window (also said "root" in beginning so it is attached to root of window not frame)

#Chose app button


#Start apps button

    #start apps code
def runApps():
    for app in apps:
        os.startfile(app)
    #start apps code

StartApps = tk.Button(root, text="Start Apps", padx=10, pady=5, fg="white", bg=color, command=runApps)
StartApps.pack() #add it to "pack" aka to that window (also said "root" in beginning so it is attached to root of window not frame)

#Start apps button

#reset button
def resetFiles():
    os.remove('QuickAppsave.txt')
    for widget in frame.winfo_children():
     widget.destroy()
    os.startfile('QuickApps.py')
    exit()


resetApps = tk.Button(root, text="Reset", padx=10, pady=5, fg="white", bg=color, command=resetFiles)
resetApps.pack() #add it to "pack" aka to that window (also said "root" in beginning so it is attached to root of window not frame)

#reset button

#Buttons
for app in apps:
    label = tk.Label(frame, text=format_path(app))
    label.pack()


root.mainloop()

with open('QuickAppsave.txt', 'w') as f:
    for app in apps:
     f.write(app + ',')
```

Comment: so i did what you said i should do, but nothing changed [same response](https://imgur.com/a/QV1beGw) and i added the code you send me.

Comment: You replaced the code where #Buttons is right? Because I tested it and it works

Comment: Yes i did, still same problem, it only shows the split after i click on choose app and close the file explorer, i guess it has smt to do with the saved .txt file and how its read in the first part of the code

Comment: Thank You! it works! but i don't understand what happened and why it used to not work

Comment: Well if you look at what happens in addApp(), you'll see that you were formatting the path before setting it to the label text. Then compare that to the bottom of your code under #Buttons and you'll see you don't do the same thing there.

Comment: ohhhh yea that confused me for a bit, thanks, now i understand